# Win32/GDI: How to use RealizePalette() to modify color table?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

According to MSDN documentation on GDI function RealizePalette():

> The **RealizePalette** function modifies the palette for the device
>   associated with the specified device context. *If the device context is
>   a memory DC, the color table for the bitmap selected into the DC is
>   modified.*

Behavior described in italics doesn't seem to work in the following code:

```
void test_color_tbl_modify(HWND hWnd) {
    // initialize BITMAPINFO struct for a mono bitmap(red&white)
    const int bmp_w = 16, bmp_h = 32;
    std::vector<BYTE> vBytes(sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 2); // for mono bitmaps, bmiColors member of BITMAPINFO contains two RGBQUAD elems
    BITMAPINFO* pbmi = reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFO*>(vBytes.data());
    {
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bih{};
        {
            bih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bih.biWidth = bmp_w;
            bih.biHeight = bmp_h;
            bih.biPlanes = 1;
            bih.biBitCount = 1;
            bih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bih.biSizeImage = ((bih.biWidth * bih.biBitCount + 31) & ~31) / 8   // each scanline aligned on DWORD boundary
                * bih.biHeight;
            bih.biClrUsed = 2;
            bih.biClrImportant = 0;
        }

        pbmi->bmiHeader = bih;
        pbmi->bmiColors[0] = RGBQUAD{0,0,255,0};        // red
        pbmi->bmiColors[1] = RGBQUAD{255,255,255,0};    // white
    }

    // create a mono DDB
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // has 1x1 mono bitmap selected into it by default
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcmem, bmp_w, bmp_h); // creates a mono-bitmap(see above)

    // draw something
    HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hdcmem, hbitmap);
    for(int y = 0; y < bmp_h; ++y) {
        for(int x = 0; x < bmp_w; ++x) {
            COLORREF col = x & 1 && y & 1 ? RGB(255, 255, 255) : RGB(0, 0, 0);
            SetPixel(hdcmem, x, y, col);
        }
    }

    // blit image to client area by creating a DIB section and 
    // copying DIBits to it from hbitmap(works as expected: red&white image)
    {
        // get DIBits
        std::vector<BYTE> vDIBits_buf(pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
        void* pvBits = vDIBits_buf.data();
        SelectObject(hdcmem, hOldBmp); // hbitmap must NOT be selected into a DC before GetDIBits() call as per documentation
        if(!GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap,
                        0, (UINT)bmp_h,
                        pvBits, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {  // resets biClrUsed & biClrImportant to 0, and pbmi->bmiColors to black&white -- why??
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"GetDIBits has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
        }

        // reset members modified(for some reason) by GetDIBits() 
        // back to their original values
        pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 2;
        pbmi->bmiColors[0] = RGBQUAD{0,0,255,0};
        pbmi->bmiColors[1] = RGBQUAD{255,255,255,0};

        // copy DIBits from hbitmap to hDIBSecion
        void* pvBits_dest = nullptr;
        HBITMAP hDIBSecion = CreateDIBSection(hdc, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits_dest, NULL, 0);
        memcpy(pvBits_dest, pvBits, pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage);

        // blit hDIBSecion to client area
        HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hdcmem, hDIBSecion);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bmp_w, bmp_h, hdcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); // blits a red&white image as expected

        // clean up
        SelectObject(hdcmem, hOldBmp);
        DeleteObject(hDIBSecion);
    }

    // blit image to client area by modifying color table of hbitmap 
    // (does not work as expected: black&white image instead of green&black)
    {    
        // initialize palette(green&black)
        std::vector<BYTE> log_palette_buf(sizeof(LOGPALETTE) + sizeof(PALETTEENTRY) * 2);
        LOGPALETTE* plplt = reinterpret_cast<LOGPALETTE*>(log_palette_buf.data());
        plplt->palNumEntries = 2;
        plplt->palVersion = 0x0300;
        PALETTEENTRY pe_black{0,0,0,0};
        PALETTEENTRY pe_green{0,255,0,0};
        plplt->palPalEntry[0] = pe_green;
        plplt->palPalEntry[1] = pe_black;

        // modify color table of hbitmap to green&black
        HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hdcmem, hbitmap); // select hbitmap into memory DC first
        HPALETTE hp = CreatePalette(plplt);
        HPALETTE hp_old = SelectPalette(hdcmem, hp, FALSE);
        RealizePalette(hdcmem); // supposed to modify color table of selected bitmap(hbitmap) according to documentation 

        // blit hbitmap to client area
        BitBlt(hdc, bmp_w, 0, bmp_w, bmp_h, hdcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); // ???blits a black&white image???

        // clean-up
        SelectObject(hdcmem, hOldBmp);
        SelectPalette(hdcmem, hp_old, FALSE);
        DeleteObject(hp);
    }

    // clean up
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcmem);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: RealizePalette was necessary back in the bad old days when video adapters could display only 256 colors.  All gone today, and has been for the past 20 years, thank heavens.  It has no remaining usefulness, you have to stop using it.

Comment: @HansPassant : Would you say the first approach is the ideal for the task? That is, drawing a monochrome image and displaying it in different colors?

Comment: You are using memory dc to create bitmap (`CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcmem, ...)`). You should use desktop `HDC` or a Window `HDC` (`CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ...)`) that gives you a high color `HBITMAP`. If for some reason you must work with palettes, use `GetDIBColorTable` and `SetDIBColorTable` instead